# How to add localization to Stripe Android strings?

Tags: java, android

I integrated Stripe for Android, however I can't see how translate Stripe strings.

Comment: please share the code that you have tried.

Comment: Share some code first

Answer (score 0):

Localization is a process so that we can have app native language as per user selection or based on app regional requirement. To do so we use different string file in resource folder of the project for different locale or language. Once it is done then the android OS manages the localization automatically. You do not need to do anything special for this untill you do not want to localize your app in the app environment only without intervention of the language settings.

I am assuming that you want to change the localization of the app based on langugae settings by the user. So in this case if the user select a particular language for the app which is not available in your string resource then in this case the default language (default is english if not made any change in your project) will be overriden. You can see the detail at [officail_site_link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization) and [general_link](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-localization-multi-language-with-examples).

Now regarding Stripe you can see the supported language at [link](https://support.stripe.com/questions/supported-languages-for-stripe-checkout). If it does not include the one you want then your app will show default language.